# DataGrid items are missing while display

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am using WPF data grid to display names (scrolling is enabled). Let us say there are 17 names. My grid displays only 15 (with increments of 5 in each vertical scroll) and 2 names are missing. Looks like 5 hard coded somewhere. Does anyone know which property should I use to display all items even if the count is less than 5?

Comment: Need to see the code. But I would guess it is the container for your grid that is giving you problems, not the grid itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you don't have to do anything extra to display all contents. Giving a fixed height to datagrid enables scroll and that's it. This doesn't hide anything. If you can share the code perhaps someone can pinpoint where it's going wrong.